# How to make a custom Web Component "height:100%" of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, height, web-component

I wrote a *Web Component* using Vue.js and *vue-custom-element*. Now I want to make *my-chat* and *my-whiteboard* Web Components "height:100%".I'm using the component like this:

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <splitpanes class="default-theme">
    <pane>
      <my-chat></my-chat>
    </pane>
    <pane>
      <my-whiteboard></my-whiteboard>
    </pane>
  </splitpanes>
</template>
```

The only way that I know is to set the height of all parents to 100% like this:

```css
html,
body,
splitpanes,
pane,
my-chat,
my-whiteboard {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```js
//main.js

...
// Load custom element plugin
Vue.use(vueCustomElement);

// Define web components
Vue.customElement("skyroom-whiteboard", Whiteboard);
Vue.customElement("skyroom-chat", Chat);
...
```

**And do this for the all tags inside web *my-chat* and *my-whiteboard* too!!!**

**The problems:**

1. This is not working for *my-* components.
2. It seems to be wrong! Isn't there any **right** way to do this?

Comment: and how about ``100vh``?

Comment: I think min-height set as 100vh might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to do it is to use

```
my-chat, my-whiteboard {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

However, when one of them becomes taller than 100vh, it will grow without the other one. So, most likely, ...

```
display: block;
height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
```

... will do a better job.

Here's an example (you don't need any the CSS after `/* let's test it */` line but I had to add it as all of them are custom elements and, by default, they have a `display` value of `inline`):

```css
my-chat,
my-whiteboard {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* let's check it */

my-chat,
my-whiteboard {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tester {
  height: 200vh;
  padding: 1rem;
}
splitpanes { display: flex; }
pane:first-child { flex-basis: 75%; }
pane:last-child { flex-grow: 1; }
body { margin: 0; }
/* don't use this line in your app, it will likely break stuff
 * I used it here because I don't have any content to break! */
.default-theme * { display: block; }
```

```html
<splitpanes class="default-theme">
  <pane>
    <my-chat>
      <tester>my-chat</tester>
    </my-chat>
  </pane>
  <pane>
    <my-whiteboard>
      <tester>my-whiteboard</tester>
    </my-whiteboard>
  </pane>
</splitpanes>
```

**Important note:** If any of your components gets parsed by Vue into actual `<div>` elements, you'll need to change the selectors accordingly (but you did say they're custom elements, so I'm guessing they're used as-is).